# MSMQ .mp files - What are the different types?

Tags: msmq, file-extension

I had MSMQ fill up on me the other day (forgot to turn off journalling on a queue) and saw in the `storage` folder that there seems to be different types of `.mp` files.

Some were `p*.mp` and are 4096K, and others are `l*.mp` and are 8K.

What are the differences between these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [plumber's mate](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/04/04/why-are-my-express-messages-being-written-to-disk.aspx):

> All MSMQ messages are written to
>   memory mapped files in the Storage
>   directory:
>
> - R*.MQ files are for Express messages
> - P*.MQ files are for Persistent (Recoverable) messages, including
>     Transactional messages
> - J*.MQ files are for Journal messages
> - L*.MQ files are bitmap indexes to the Persistent and Journal files